# How to add edit for field value on form submit using jquery

Tags: jquery

Ill keep my form simple.

```
<form id="checkout">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="hidden" name="optin" value="">

  <input type="submit" value="Purchase with signup">
  <input type="sibmit" name="Purchase and Signup">
</form>
```

NOTE: I can not edit the form directly. So I can not move the button outside of the form and trigger the submit event using submit()

I need to be able to update the value of name="optin" to 1 if the user submits the form by clicking the "Purchase and Signup" field. My first guess was to use jQuery to update the value. If however, there is another way to add this to the POST request the Im all ears.

Comment: Add click event to Purchase and Signup event, `preventDefault()` of the click event object,  modify the value, submit the form via `JQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to change the value of input hidden, refer below code where you can use click handler for button and 'e.preventDefault()' will stop default behavior of form submit. you can change the input value and then submit form

HTML

```
<form id="checkout">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="hidden" name="option" value="">

  <input type="submit" value="Purchase with signup" id="purchaseWithSignup">
  <input type="submit" name="Purchase and Signup" id="purchaseAndSignup">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#purchaseAndSignup").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('input[value="option"]').val(1);
   $("#checkout").submit();
});
```

Comment: This hasnt worked. Although I tested withthout the submit() and it still submitted the form.

Comment: can you change the type="submit" to type="button" for Purchase and Signup an then try

Comment: I think its more likely to do with the fact the form is submitting via ajax.